# The library 'javacv-android-arm.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-ndk, google-code

How can I resolve this issue?

I've just copy javacv jar files under my project `Lib` folder and got this error!

I can find this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/issues/detail?id=298) from google but the page can not be opened because of google restrictions policy in my country unfortunately.

The reason I include these jars in my android application is that I do not want to use `openCV manager`. I want to statically link `openCV` library to my project. I am trying to run my app on `Samsung Galaxy S5`.

Here is the `LogCat` errors I've got:

```
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition] The library 'javacv-android-arm.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition] The following libraries were found:
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniARToolKitPlus.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniavcodec.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniavdevice.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniavfilter.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniavformat.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniavutil.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjnicvkernels.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_calib3d.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_contrib.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_core.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_features2d.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_flann.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_highgui.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_imgproc.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_legacy.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_ml.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_nonfree.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_objdetect.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_photo.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_stitching.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_video.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniopencv_videostab.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjnipostproc.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniswresample.so
[2014-07-16 10:13:57 - face-recognition]  - com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/android-arm/libjniswscale.so
```

**EDIT-1**
After I follow the instruction in [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv), thanks to [PRAKASH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3778703/prakash-ubhadiya) I could resolve these errors, but I have got other errors which are totally related to `NoClassDefFoundError`. I really give up. I can not resolve the issue, so any help would be really appreciated. Here are my new errors:

```
07-22 08:48:54.472: E/dalvikvm(11694): Could not find class 'com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$MatVector', referenced from method org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.PersonRecognizer.train
07-22 08:48:54.472: W/dalvikvm(11694): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 108 (Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$MatVector;) in Lorg/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/PersonRecognizer;
07-22 08:48:54.472: D/dalvikvm(11694): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001c
07-22 08:48:54.472: D/dalvikvm(11694): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x00c9 at 0x28 in Lorg/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/PersonRecognizer;.train
07-22 08:48:54.472: D/AndroidRuntime(11694): Shutting down VM
07-22 08:48:54.472: W/dalvikvm(11694): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41737c08)
07-22 08:48:54.477: E/AndroidRuntime(11694): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 08:48:54.477: E/AndroidRuntime(11694): Process: org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition, PID: 11694
07-22 08:48:54.477: E/AndroidRuntime(11694): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download [Javacv latest version](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/bytedeco/javacv/0.8/javacv-0.8-bin.zip)

and extract it and put 
`ffmpeg.jar` ,`javacv.jar` ,`javacpp.jar` and `opencv.jar` in `libs` folder of your project

and also extract all *.so from extracted

```
opencv-android-arm.jar,ffmpeg-android-arm.jar files.
```

and put all *.so files inside **libs/armeabi** folder

for more information [click here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv)

it may solve your problem .

Comment: exactly, and you should also add `*.so` files extracted from the other `*-android-*.jar` files to your other libs folders, like `opencv-android-x86.jar` to **libs/x86**.

If you're using Android Studio/gradle, these directories (armeabi, x86...) are to be created under **jniLibs** instead of **libs**.

Comment: Ok, thanks to PRAKASH and @ph0b, I will try this solution and let you guys know about the result

Comment: Ok, I have done every steps you mentioned exactly. Now I have got link error on **com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib**, Eclipse can not resolve it to type :(. I have got this error on every other **com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*** libraries which I import :(

Comment: change imported Package name to  org.bytedeco.javacv.cpp.*;

Comment: changed it, but this package is not resolved too.@PRAKASHUBHADIYA

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: javacv0.8, the link you gave in your answer@PRAKASHUBHADIYA

Comment: Thank you very much, all tutorials are out of date and have some errors, this works even with the latest version 0.11! thanks

Comment: what a lol... subfolder makes the trick, but i would have never thought about it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet installed the Android Development Environment, you can follow this link which contains everything you need to get started quickly. Watch the tutorial video and follow the instructions underneath to install Eclipse, the Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Android development and create a new project.

Once you have installed everything and have created the project, use the following procedure to import JavaCV libraries to the Android project:

Download the JavaCv libraries:
a. From this link download "[javacv-0.7-bin.zip](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.7-bin.zip&can=2&q=) " and extract the files:
- javacpp.jar
- javacv.jar
- javacv-android-arm.jar
b. From this link download "[javacv-0.7-cppjars.zip](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/detail?name=javacv-0.7-cppjars.zip&can=2&q=)" and extract the files:
- opencv-2.4.8-android-arm.jar
-  ffmpeg-2.1.1-android-arm.jar

Go to File > New > Folder, select your project as parent folder, type "libs/armeabi" as Folder name, and click Finish.

Copy javacpp.jar and javacv.jar into the "libs" folder.

Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-2.4.8-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.1.1-android-arm.jar directly into the "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any of the subdirectories found in the JAR files. (The easiest way to extract the .so files from the .jar is by using 7-ZIP software which can be downloaded here).

Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".

Select both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the "libs" folder.

Finally,import JavaCV functions to your code

```
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
 import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

and use some sample code to check that everything is working correctly.