# How to setup javacv, opencv for android

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg

I want to use FFmpegFrameRecorder for creating video from images. I have create sample project in netbeans sets the javacv and opencv it works.

But how to set for android. I have follow this link
http://javacv4android.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-import-javacv-libraries-to.html>

But at the end it give error Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR
I did all things that need to resolve INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR but not fix.

Please tell me the procedure to setup javacv and opencv for android?

Comment: please check this [link][1] it may helps you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24774963/3778703

Comment: Is there any way to use only ffmpegFrameRecorder instead I configure javacv and opencv, I only configure FFmpeg PRAKASH UBHADIYA?

Comment: It is not possible in javacv library . if you want to use ffmpeg only then you have knowledge of android ndk and jni .

Comment: please use javacv , compilation process of FFMPEG is hard

http://stackoverflow.com/a/24309519/3778703 

https://enoent.fr/blog/2014/06/20/compile-ffmpeg-for-android/